# Jest test failing "Error: thrown: "Exceeded timeout of <x> for a test."

Tags: node.js, jestjs

This was a bit of a frustrating one for me and I am still not entirely sure why the code/ide behaved like this.

I was getting the following error on one test that randomly started happening with no code changes that touched this test. I ran --detectOpenHandles that revealed no potential async functions that would be the culprit. I also tried running jest with --forceExit with no change.

I noticed in intellij, the parameters of the test function looked different from other tests. It was showing (object: DoneCallback, method) in the method parameter of the second argument of test().

[image]

To test, I removed my test code and did a simple expect 1 to be 1 test and it still continued to fail with a time out. After rewriting the test method line, the parameter area didn't show the object and method suggestion and the test worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. As mentioned in the question body, I was able to resolve the issue by simply rewriting the test with the same code.

I hope I can save someone some time should they ever run into the same situation I did.

If anyone has a specific explanation as to why the code all of a sudden started behaving like this, Please provide that info.